# Create a NuGet repo in JFrog Artifactory with GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, artifactory, jfrog-cli

Aim: Create nuget package repository in JFrog Artifactory for .NET Core library.

Current status: I'm trying to create repo(nuget type) with use of repo-template in JFrog artifactory(those are few lines of code in GitHub actions *.yml file):

```
 - name: Repository Creation
    working-directory: templates
    run: |
      jf rt rc virtual-repo-template.json --vars "key1=test"
```

I get error: 403, Forbidden.

While creating docker image and pushing it into Artifactory Packages goes all well.

Comment: can you please add more information about the reason for the 403? You can increase the log level by configuring the JFROG_CLI_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG environment variable.

Comment: 403 is forbidden, check which user you are using to create the repository as only admins have the access to create repos

Comment: @MuhammedKashif the issue was related with 'admin' role.

Comment: Is the issue resolved now?

Comment: Yes we can say that, I had different case but related with admin role